# What happens to Portal child when container or its content is removed?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, removechild, react-portal, react-component-unmount

I plan to use [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for a solution I am building, and I am trying to understand what happens to the child when the container or its content is removed.

My code:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)
```

Where container is a HTML element.

What is then going to happen to child in the following situations?

Case 1: container is removed from the DOM:

```
container.remove()

container.parentElement.removeChild(container)
```

Case 2: container content is unmounted

```
ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(container)
```